# How can I add significance labels to a paired boxplot with discrete x-axis values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

As the header says, I'm am trying to add significance stars into a boxplot with paired boxplots and a discrete x-axis with geom_signif. Is there any possibility to set the `xmin` and `xmax` values above one of the paired boxplots? As you can see in the attached image of the Plot, I managed to show the significance level for the differences in 'Behandlung' (= K and T), but I would also need to give significance levels between silicon '-' and silicon '+'.

[image]
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHd5k.png)

Here is the code that creates the image:

```
blf <- data.frame(min.Blattlf = c(34,28,27,27,22,23,34,39,39,21,39,24,27,25,24,26,29,21,20,29,23,20,26,20,19,18,17,15),
                   Behandlung = c('K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','K','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T'),
                   Silizium = c('-','-','-','-','-','-','-','+','+','+','+','+','+','+','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','+','+','+','+','+','+','+'))

ggplot(data = blf, aes(x = Behandlung, y = Min.Blattleitfähigkeit, fill = Silizium)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 2) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = 'Behandlung', y = expression(paste("min. Blattleitfähigkeit ", (mmol~m^-2~s^-1)))) +
  geom_signif(annotations = "***", y_position = 41, xmin = c('K'), xmax = 'T')
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, margin(b = 0, unit = "pt")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, margin(l = 0, unit = "pt")),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

If it doesn't work with ggsignif, are there any other possible solutions?

Thank you for your help,
Mo

Comment: Please make your question reproducible. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I edited the code so that it should be easily reproducible now.

Comment: Take a look at the examples from this package https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot